# move Odoo large database (1.2TB)

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have to move a large Odoo(v13) database almost 1.2TB(DATABASE+FILESTORE), I can't use the UI for that(keeps loading for 10h+ without a result) and I dont want to only move postgresql database so I need file store too,
What should I do? extract db and copy past the filestore folder?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this help: [How To Move a PostgreSQL Data Directory to a New Location on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04) ?

Comment: Hm, on re-reading you want to move the file store too, but there is no info how large the file store is, compared to the database size...)    And I am asking myself is this question is on-topic for stackoverflow.com...

Comment: thanks for your reply, yeah thats the first thing came to mind, but Odoo needs filestore too(where attachements are saved) to work properly.

Comment: P.S. If you do a **copy** (in stead of a move) then you end up with two working systems, and if the new system is working, you can break down the old one....

Comment: Just for information: when using the UI's "backup with filestore" Odoo will create a zip file with dump and filestore into the temp (linux mostly `/tmp`) folder of your OS. That means you'll need at least 1.2 TB free space for that operation. Doing the strategy in the first answer like using pg_dump/pg_restore and like copying or rsyncing the filestore is much better in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move database and filestore separately. Move your Odoo PostgreSQL database with normal Postgres backup/restore cycle (not the Odoo UI backup/restore), this will copy the database to your new server. Then move your Odoo filestore to new location as filesystem level copy. This is enough to get the new environment running.

I assume you mean moving to a new server, not just moving to a new location on same filesystem on the same server.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean, moving to a new server, Filestore isn't encrypted or something? I can just move it separately and it will work?

Comment: Filestore is not encrypted. The folders have a hash based folder naming to work well in large scale but it will work on the new environment as such.

Comment: Thanks a lot, im on it, I will try it and report back the results.